# DC offset charging using battery's own voltage?

Tags: operational-amplifier, dc, generator, charging, offset

Pardon my awful drawing, I also omitted any voltage regulator going into the battery for simplicity. I have an extremely low (0-1.25V) "generator" DC source that raps up to that voltage and a bit less than 2 amps for a period of maybe 10 seconds at a time that I'm trying to capture energy from and store in 12V a lead acid car battery. A DC multiplier, charge pump, or inverter/transformer/rectifier combo may work, but will soak up a lot of that little generated energy for themselves. I know if I had another 12V source at the exact same voltage as the battery that I could precisely regulate I could just put the generator in series with it and charge the first battery, but I feel like that kind of defeats the purpose.

Instead, I was thinking maybe if I had an non-inverting op-amp powered by a small (3VDC) cell riding atop the battery's 12V and used a micro controller to make the op-amp provide the exact 12.XXX volts the battery was at prior to the generator powering up signal to the negative of the generator, maybe I can have the generator push only what it produces into the battery and nothing else since the op-amp is outputting the battery's exact voltage. Maybe put a diode between the op-amp and generator.

Question is: am I nuts? It feels like I accidentally made a perpetual motion machine but I've never designed a charging system with such low output before so I'm trying my best to conserve every last watt. The micro processor will deal with the rise in voltage from the generator via switches and software, so just assume the op-amp is always what the battery's voltage is without the generator's voltage bumping it up. Can this work and if not why? Will it work with any modifications? Any proposals on how to efficiently step up ~1V to over 12V? Thanks
[image: DC offset circuit]

Comment: I don't really understand what you're doing here, but all current that comes out of an op-amp comes in from the op-amp's power supply. All you are doing here is charging the 3V battery.

Comment: 5V x 1A x 10 seconds is not a tiny amount of power. Are you sure a usual power converter can't work for you?

Comment: I'm going into the negative terminal of the 3V battery so wouldn't that just mean the 3V battery isn't charging but is instead riding 12V above ground? Just talked to the generator guy, from what I'm told the generator "ramps up" to a bit less than 2A over that period, and it does so more exponentially than linearly and it may in fact peak out at about 1.25V. I'll edit the post sorry.

Comment: Indeed you are pushing current through the 3V battery the "right" way so you're discharging it.

Comment: Yeah. Question is, if I'm super precise at timing and with the voltage level at the amp's output can I make it so the only current flow comes from the generator and only goes into the 12V battery

Comment: No because the current flow is coming through the 3V battery, through the op-amp, through the generator, and going back into the negative terminal of the 3V battery....

Comment: Ok, what if I omit the 3V cell and just cap the op-amp at the battery's voltage prior to charging while the generator is active?

Comment: then your current is still going along the same path but without the 3V battery in the path...

Comment: Right, and since the battery won't charge itself wouldn't the generated current be able to push itself into the battery while it's riding atop the op-amp's 12V?

Comment: Current flows in loops. If current flows out of an op-amp it flows in through the positive power pin. If current flows into an op-amp it flows out through the negative power pin.

Comment: Ah so I would essentially be charging and discharging the battery at the same time which is a no no for lead acid and would result in basically 0 battery charge. I guess I just don't understand why the extra voltage I'm putting into the circuit via the generator wouldn't push the extra power into the battery since the amp only takes what it needs and would be locked at around 12V anyway by the micro processor.

Comment: What is the nature of the "variable DC source"? In the text you specify a range of 0-1.25 V, in the schematic you mention 0- 5V. The solutions would be very different.

Comment: Sorry, edited. From what I understand, it's a graphene sheet that when rolled over generates a DC current. I'm told that it "develops" a positive voltage on one end as a wheel rolls over it and it will peak out near 1.25V at about 2A. If I can efficiently oscillate transform and rectify it then that would be great but I'm not sure if I can.

Comment: So you have a 100 square miles graphene sheet and a one mile diameter wheel?

Comment: I wish. I have no faith this will be practical and little faith it will work at all. I'm just trying to step up whatever we get into something that can go into a 12V battery and help someone else make a little proof of concept demo.

Comment: @baraka it's not possible to charge and discharge a battery at the same time.

Comment: @baraka Op-amps take power from their power supply to the output. They don't somehow "mix" the + and - power supplies. All current that goes out comes from the +, and all current that goes in goes to the -

Comment: a circuit that *does* "mix" the + and - power supplies to create a middle-voltage output is called.... a buck converter. Dun dun duuuuuuuuuun!

Comment: Yep. I'm probably gonna have to do something like cascade a few boost converters or find an inverter/transformer/rectifier combo that can work off a 1V or lower input. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

An op-amp doesn't "mix" current from both inputs to make the output. If you need 30% of the voltage it doesn't take 30% of the current from the negative supply and 70% from the positive supply. It always wastes power. All current that goes out the output comes from the positive supply, and all current that goes into the output goes to the negative supply.

So you can see that your circuit is just an overly complicated way of putting the variable voltage source and the 3V voltage source in series.

A circuit that *does* "mix current" to get an in-between voltage is called a buck converter. A circuit that "unmixes current" is called a boost converter. But you ruled those out.

Comment: Thanks I get that now and I figured it wouldn't work. The variable DC should be a low power energy harvester anyway so idk why we're even trying to get more than 5V out of it, which should be feasible with a booster or two.